# Xcode button linking error?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hey I was wondering is their any possible way I can link two actions to the same button in Xcode? I've already tried but keep getting this error:  "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException". So i'm guessing I am not able to do that? See what i'm trying to do is
make a button play a sound but that same button is also linked to starting a new round in the game. How would I go about doing this? I've currently got this going in my .m file.

```
#import "BullsEyeViewController.h"

@interface BullsEyeViewController ()

@end

@implementation BullsEyeViewController



{
int _currentValue;
int _targetValue;
int _score;
int _round;
}


- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *buttonName=[sender currentTitle];
NSString *soundFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                     pathForResource:buttonName ofType:@"mp3"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)
                                 [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &
                                  soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self startNewGame];
[self updateLabels];



UIImage *thumbImageNormal = [UIImage
                             imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Normal"];
[self.slider setThumbImage:thumbImageNormal
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *thumbImageHighlighted = [UIImage
                                  imageNamed:@"SliderThumb-Highlighted"];
[self.slider setThumbImage:thumbImageHighlighted
                  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
UIImage *trackLeftImage =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderTrackLeft"]
 resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 14)];

[self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:trackLeftImage
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *trackRightImage =
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderTrackRight"]
 resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 14, 0, 14)];

[self.slider setMaximumTrackImage:trackRightImage
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }

- (void)startNewRound
{
_round += 1;
_targetValue = 1 + arc4random_uniform(100);
_currentValue = 50;
self.slider.value = _currentValue;
}

- (void)startNewGame
{
_score = 0;
_round = 0;
[self startNewRound];



}

- (void)updateLabels
{
self.targetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                         _targetValue];
self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                        _score];
self.roundLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                        _round];

}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)showAlert
{
int difference = abs(_targetValue - _currentValue);
int points = 100 - difference;

NSString *title;
if (difference == 0) {
    title = @"Perfect!";
    points += 100;
             } else if (difference < 5) {
                 title = @"You almost had it!";
                 if (difference == 1) {
                     points += 50;
                 }
             } else if (difference < 10 ) {
                 title = @"Pretty good!";
             } else {
                 title = @"Not even close...";
             }

            _score+=points;

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %d points", points];

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
initWithTitle: title
message:message
delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alertView show];

}


-(IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)slider
{
_currentValue = lroundf(slider.value);

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{
[self startNewRound];
[self updateLabels];
}


-(IBAction)startOver
{
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.duration = 1;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction
                             functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];


[self startNewGame];
[self updateLabels];

[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}





@end
```

And here's my .h file.

```
 //
 //  BullsEyeViewController.h
 //  BullsEye
 //
 //  Created by Sebastian Shelley on 28/04/2014.
 //  Copyright (c) 2014 Sebastian Shelley. All rights reserved.
 //

 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

 @interface BullsEyeViewController : UIViewController
 <UIAlertViewDelegate>


 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *targetLabel;

 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;

 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *roundLabel;

 -(IBAction)showAlert;

 -(IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)slider;

 -(IBAction)startOver;

 - (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender;
```

@end

Some help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide the full crash log ?

Comment: actually what the error would u get

Comment: Why not you use the one method to perform 2 stuffs??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an action like this to the button

```
-(IBAction)myButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
 [self playSound:sender];
 [self startNewRound:Sender];
}
```

Comment: Sorry add that to the .h file or the .m file?

Comment: the code goes to the .m file. The declaration -(IBAction)myButtonPressed:(id)sender; goes to the .h file. Don't forget to link this action to the button from the Interface builder

Comment: Sorry i'm pretty big newb to this. Um but won't I need the code at the top to play the sound? I've tried a few times with your code but i can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Use only one action, just set a BOOL to check if you need to play the sound or not.

Example code would be:

```
-(IBAiction)btnPressed:(id)sender
{
  if(playsound)
  {
    [self playSound];
    playsound = NO;
  }
  [self startOver];
}
```

And then whenever you want the saund to be played again just set `playsound` to `YES` and next time user presses the button it will play the sound again